# Django. Url cant find view

Tags: python, html, django, url, django-urls

I need help with {% url (url to template) %} when i try to open another view i see a NoRewerseMatch error.

here is my html file:

```
{% load static %}
<head>
    <link href='{% static "navbar_style.css" %}' rel="stylesheet", type="text/css">
</head>
<header>
    <nav class="headlist">
--->    <a href='{% url "home" %}'><img id = "img1" src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" alt="logo"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a>Zajęcia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

my app(pages)/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'pages'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name='home_view'),
    path('index/', views.index_view, name='index_view'),
]
```

views.py

```
import...

# Create your views here.
def home_view(request):
    listoftexts = Text.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {
        'listoftexts': listoftexts
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', context)
def index_view(request):
    listoftexts = Text.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {
        'listoftexts': listoftexts
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href='{% url "pages:home_view" %}'><img id = "img1" src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" alt="logo"></a>
```

**You can do it like this.**

Answer (score 0):

The name of the view is `home_view`:

```
path('', views.home_view, name='home_view'),
```

so you can use the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) with:

```
<a href="{% url 'home_view' %}">
```

If you use an `app_name` in the `urls.py`, you also need to prefix this in the url:

```
<a href="{% url 'pages:home_view' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `url_name` should be `home_view` not `home`. The name parameter in the `path` function is what you use to refernce the view.